# Cross-validation and variance calculation in the `gstat` package in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

Good day,

I am getting some difficulty when trying to calculate the variance from an inverse distance krig done in the `gstat` package. I would also like to run a cross-validation on an independent test set of variables, but I am not sure of how to do so in R with spatial data. Using the `meuse` dataset, this is what I attempted for calculating variance:

```
data(meuse); coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y 

#randomly sample to get training and test data for later cross-validation
set.seed = (123)

sub1 <- nrow(meuse@data); len1 <- ceiling(sub1*2/3)

m.train <- meuse
m.train@data <- meuse@data[1:len1,]
m.train@coords <- meuse@coords[1:len1,]

m.test <- meuse
m.test@data <- meuse@data[(len1+1):sub1,]
m.test@coords  <- meuse@coords[(len1+1):sub1,]

 ## load grids:
data(meuse.grid); coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE; fullgrid(meuse.grid) <- TRUE

zinc.id <- krige(zinc~1, m.train, meuse.grid) ## inverse distance weighting

# --- My attempt at calculation of variance
rmse.id <- sqrt(mean((meuse.test@data$zinc - zinc.id@data$var1.pred)^2))

Warning message:
In meuse.test@data$z - zinc.id@data$var1.pred :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I can see why I am getting the error, but I am not sure how to proceed. I can do the cross-validation outside of `R` with a bit of trouble, but I really would like to keep all my working within `R`. Any suggestions would be most welcomed.

Kurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform this kind of comparison, you need to use `meuse` and not `meuse.grid` as the `newdata`. Or even better, use `krige.cv`.

For example using the `meuse` dataset:

```
kr_cv = krige.cv(log(zinc)~1, meuse, vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04))
kr_cv[1:5,]
       coordinates var1.pred  var1.var observed    residual      zscore fold
1 (181072, 333611)  6.784729 0.1681011 6.929517  0.14478795  0.35314023    1
2 (181025, 333558)  6.777372 0.1635077 7.039660  0.26228828  0.64864901    2
3 (181165, 333537)  6.294508 0.1723531 6.461468  0.16696067  0.40216530    3
4 (181298, 333484)  6.033072 0.2191244 5.549076 -0.48399603 -1.03394256    4
5 (181307, 333330)  5.576879 0.1643513 5.594711  0.01783242  0.04398694    5
```

From this you can easily calculate the RMSE of the cross-validation. The `automap` package (disclaimer: which I wrote) contains a convienient function that can calculate a lot of these stats for you. Normally it only accepts the output of `autoKrige.cv`, but using a small hack you can still use it:

```
library(automap)
compare.cv(list(krige.cv_output = kr_cv))
            krige.cv_output
mean_error        0.0003146
me_mean           5.345e-05
MAE                  0.2898
MSE                  0.1515
MSNE                 0.8607
cor_obspred          0.8416
cor_predres         0.05449
RMSE                 0.3892
RMSE_sd              0.5391
URMSE                0.3892
iqr                  0.3949
```

Comment: Thanks a million Paul, your package certainly looks helpful and I will definitely use it. However I am still a bit unsure with how to include the test and training datasets. Going back to my example would the correct formula to run a cross validation on the unseen (test) data set be `kr.cv.id<-krige.cv(zinc~1, m.train, newdata=m.test) #For inverse distance interpolation`